# JavaScript Uncheck Box when another box is Checked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I a have a problem with my JS code.

I have 2 checkbox.
Each checkbox when will check will show a different div with information.
The user can choose to  check just one checkbox.
When i press Option 1 the div will show. IF i uncheck Option 1 the div will disappear. This is ok.
The problem is when i check the the second option without uncheck mannualy all div are display. I tried to search a  problem like mine but i doesn't find a correct answer. 
Thank you help.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMe (box) {

        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("o1");
        var vis = "none";
        for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) {
            if(chboxs[i].checked){
                vis = "block";
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;

    }

    function cbChange(obj) {

        if(obj.checked)
        {

            var cbs = document.getElementsByName("o1");
            for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
                cbs[i].checked = false;
            }
            obj.checked = true;
        }
    }


</script>
```

HTML

```
                <input type="checkbox" name="o1"  class="checked" onclick="showMe('div1')" onchange='cbChange(this)'>Option 1 - Recommended

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <input type="checkbox" name="o1"  class="checked" onclick="showMe('div2')" onchange='cbChange(this)'>Option 2 - Optional
```

Comment: The reason for all the `<div>` appearing is the line of the code `var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("o1");` here try to get the element by its specific `id` not the name.

Comment: Seems like you need a radio button rather than a list of checkboxes. Checkboxes shouldn't have the same name. You could utilize a class for that purpose.

Comment: so i need to add id in checkbox ?

Comment: You should completely redesign your solution. Do these checkboxes ever get submitted or are they here just to show this additional information?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let myInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("myInputs");
    for (i = 0; i < myInputs.length; i++) {
      myInputs[i].addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        for (j = 0; j < myInputs.length; j++) {
          let divElm = document.getElementById(
            myInputs[j].getAttribute("data-div")
          );
          if (myInputs[j].checked) {
            divElm.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            divElm.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

```css
     div {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
      <label for="">input 1</label>
    <input
      type="radio"
      class="myInputs"
      value="1"
      data-div="div1"
      name="myradio"
    />
    <label for="">input 2</label>
    <input
      type="radio"
      class="myInputs"
      value="2"
      data-div="div2"
      name="myradio"
    />
    <div id="div1">i am div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">i am div 2</div>
```

Comment: let me know if you need explanation

Comment: An explanation (at least a short one) should always be included in an answer. Even if OP didn't need one, future readers might.

Comment: But i decided to do like this 
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

            var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");

            var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);

            $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();

            $(targetBox).show();

        });

    });


</script>

                <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="option1"> Option 1 - Recommended
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="option2"> Option 2 - Optional

Comment: depends on you , this can be done with different ways , i just tried to give you the idea . actually if i want to do this i would consider assigning certain classes to a certain html structure and write JS for it , so i can use it globally whereever i need , it's not a good idea to do these things with `id` or for certain elements

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

            var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");

            var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);

            $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();

            $(targetBox).show();

        });

    });


</script>
```

```
            <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="option1"> Option 1 - Recommended
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="option2"> Option 2 - Optional
```

```
<div id="div2" class="option2 box" style="display: none">
<div id="div1" class="option1 box" style="display: none">
```

Comment: My version is with radio buttons is more simple i guess

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution based on using radioboxes unique values:

```js
function handleClick(target) {
  const currentId = target.value.split('option')[1];
  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i++) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
  document.getElementById('div' + currentId).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.content div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="option1" name="option" value="option1" onclick="handleClick(this)">
  <label for="option1">Option 1 - Recommended</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="option2" name="option" value="option2" onclick="handleClick(this)">
  <label for="option2">Option 2 - Optional</label>
</form> 

<div class="content">
  <div id="div1" class="box"><h1>BOX 1</h1></div>
  <div id="div2" class="box"><h1>BOX 2</h1></div>
</div>
```